# What is the best practice for preventing CSRF when storing tokens in cookie storage?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I'm implementing a website using node.js and express.js that uses JWT tokens in order to validate requests as well as logins. To login to the website (GET request), I'm using the following scheme:

1. Tokens are stored in cookie storage
2. Tokens are then automatically sent with each http(s) request, which are then detected by middleware, used to sent the "req.headers.authorization" header, and after which the user is redirected to the protected area of the website (http://www.example.com/)

I'm using this approach so that I can protect the root level of a website, as well as to create separate protected areas (e.g. http://www.example.com/protected_area_1 and http://www.example.com/protected_area_2), since the project aim of the different areas will most likely be very different, and I want to avoid storing everything in one giant single page web application.

For API requests, I'm sticking to using html5storage and a token based approach - cookies are only being used for the actual login.

Now my question is: Do I have to worry about preventing CSRF attacks using this approach? Since I'm only using cookies to store the actual token to login with, is it correct the only thing an attacker could do would be to cause a user to login against their will? None of the actual user functions would be validated against cookies.